# Check Access Form Field for Null, if Not Null then Call the Add Feature

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this simple Access Form that when you fill out the form and forget to fill out the Business Unit field, a msgBox will pop up telling you so and setFocus to that very Combo box. If it is Not null, I want to call the next feature.  The first part of this code works, but the when it is notNull it wil not carry on.

```
 Private Sub Image_AddNon_RPS_Button_Click()

 If IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Business Unit!", vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
         End If
    Me.Combo_BU_Selector.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
If Not IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then
    Call Add_RPS_LINE
        End If
End Sub
```

Does anybody see where I am totally out in left field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got an extra `Exit Sub` (the one after the first `MsgBox`) that stops your code from doing what you want. Also, your first `End If` is in the wrong location.

Try something like this instead:

```
Private Sub Image_AddNon_RPS_Button_Click()

  If IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then                     ' No business unit 
      MsgBox "Please Select a Business Unit!", vbOKOnly  ' Tell user 
      Me.Combo_BU_Selector.SetFocus                      ' Focus the control
      Exit Sub                                           ' Exit the method
  End If                                                 ' End the IsNull test

  Call Add_RPS_LINE      ' You only get here if the above doesn't execute
End Sub
```

It helps if you learn to properly indent your code to match `If` and `End If` visually, so you can see where they line up (match) and where they don't. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the code change. I replaced the existing code, however when I do have a BU Selected, meaning it is not null, nothing happens still. The Add_RPS_Line Sub works by itself if I institute the Button_Click on that particular code.

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the indentation of your code to:

```
Private Sub Image_AddNon_RPS_Button_Click()
   If IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then
      MsgBox "Please Select a Business Unit!", vbOKOnly
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Me.Combo_BU_Selector.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
   If Not IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then
      Call Add_RPS_LINE
   End If
End Sub
```

You can clearly see that the `Exit Sub` in the middle will terminate the function before it gets to `Call Add_RPS_LINE`.

If you look at the two `If` statements you have, you can see that they are almost the same and so an `Else` is in order, resulting in this simpler and more readable code.

```
Private Sub Image_AddNon_RPS_Button_Click()
   If IsNull(Me.BU_Selected_Add) Then
      MsgBox "Please Select a Business Unit!", vbOKOnly
      Me.Combo_BU_Selector.SetFocus
   Else
      Call Add_RPS_LINE
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this as the answer, it is more elegant and avoids ExitSub. I try to avoid that as much as possible, I don't know why, it just seems like cheating to me. This answer is completely readable, and as simple as possible. Just what one would expect from a professional stand point. That is my opinion. It's also the way I would have written it.